# Nimbus-like look for JavaFX UI components

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, look-and-feel

JavaFX allows styling of UI components via CSS. For seamless integration into an existing Swing application it would be nice to make the FX components look like Swing components with Nimbus look and feel. Are there any existing approaches to this? So far I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to code up some JavaFX CSS to make JavaFX look like nimbus, although it would be some work it would certainly be possible.  Nimbus UI properties are published here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html

Setting the variables that are defined in the caspian.css file to those in the link above will get you most except for the gradients, drop shadows and images.